# IntelliJ IDEA Terminal not see commands

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, flatpak

I'm using Fedora 35 Linux and I installed IntelliJ IDEA via flatpak, and when I try to use the `docker` command in the IDEA's terminal window, it gives me the following error message:

```
bash-5.1$ docker
bash: docker: command not found
```

In a normal terminal window I can use the `docker` command fine with my user.

I installed the fish terminal too for my user but the IDEA not see the `fish` command too.

The Terminal config in the IDEA looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Type `echo $PATH` in Idea terminal, what would you see?

Comment: `bash-5.1$ echo $PATH
/home/spatrik/.local/bin:/home/spatrik/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin:`  


My username on the system is `spatrik`, so it is looks like correct. Maybe missing here something? In a normal terminal the output is: `/home/spatrik/.local/bin /home/spatrik/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following command in the IDEA Shell path setting will solve the problem:

```
/usr/bin/env -- flatpak-spawn --host bash
```

[image]

Comment: I got this issue when using this command: https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code/issues/315, however `/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn --host zsh` (My default shell is zsh) worked well

Comment: I just ran into this but my problem was that I was unable to see zsh, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I installed IntelliJ IDEA via flatpak

IntelliJ IDEA's terminal can't see docker executables because the environment running the IDEA is a sandbox and there is no docker or other programs. You could use `ls /usr/bin/docker` to check it.

You can install a non-flatpack/non-snap version if you want to use those programs: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html

Comment: Yes, the output is:
`bash-5.1$ ls /usr/bin/docker
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/docker': No such file or directory`

Is this the only way or can I somehow change the flatpak running environment? Or pass my environment variables to this sandbox environment for example.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up with flatpak and installed via snap:
https://snapcraft.io/intellij-idea-ultimate

Terminal works as expected.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34744395)